# Al hacer innerHTML, no reconoce la clases de jquery

Tags: javascript, html

```
$1('#componentesin').addEventListener("click", function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    if(ev.target.id=="addItem"){
        let iditem = ev.target.dataset.producto;
        let template1 = `
        <select data-placeholder='Seleccione personal' name='personal' class='chosen-select'>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="0">test</option>
            <option value="0">test2</option>
               $//{data}
        </select>`;    

        $1('#modal-body').innerHTML =  template1;
    }
});
```

Al mostrarlo en el HTML, no me reconoce como un combo autocomplete, tan solo como un simple combo, en la etiqueta select class='chosen-select', pertenece a una libria de jquery.

Pero si me funciona cuando la ejecuto directamente en el HTML.

Comment: Inspecciona el código (en chrome p.ej.) para ver qué le pasa cuando lo ejecutas por js y no directamente en html.

Comment: Se crea el elemento, pero, jquery no reconoce la clase chosen-select

Comment: Tuve un problema parecido, lo solucione usando on.("click"), eso era con jquery, ahora estoy utilizando solo js.

Comment: jquery no tiene que reconocer una clase css, esto lo hace el navegador. Hay una cosa que me llama la atención - en jquery no se usaba `$('#modal-body').html(template1);`? Entiendo que tu versión es superior pero aun así...

Comment: function $1(selector){
        return document.querySelector(selector);
    }   ------ solo es una funcion de javascript, $1('#id') es igual a queryselector()